# SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values - Try to use DEFAULT values

Tags: sql, plsql

Im trying to build a table with `DEFAULT value`:

```
CREATE TABLE OrderMenu
(
orderid NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
pid NUMBER(4),
quantity NUMBER(3),
rowTotal NUMBER(4) DEFAULT 0);
```

And I wrote this Trigger to calculate new `rowTotal` value:

```
CREATE TRIGGER orderMenuTrig AFTER INSERT ON OrderMenu
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE TrigOrderID NUMBER;
BEGIN
     TrigOrderID := :new.orderid;
     UPDATE OrderMenu 
                     SET rowtotal = rowtotal+1;
                     WHERE trigorderid = OrderMenu.orderid;
END;
/
```

But When I try to `INSERT` into `OrderMenu` table:

```
INSERT INTO OrderMenu VALUES(1234, 111, 2);
```

I got this error:

```
Error starting at line : 126 in command -
INSERT INTO OrderMenu VALUES(1234, 111, 2)
Error at Command Line : 126 Column : 13
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values
00947. 00000 -  "not enough values"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I'll appreciate any help to solve it, I'm new with SQL / PLSQL.

Comment: INSERT INTO t (c1, c2 ,c3) VALUES (1,2,3)

Comment: Added a solution for your trigger. I'm not sure if your intent is to just increment the rowtotal based only on the default/old value of rowtotal for the current row, but since that's the code in your trigger in question, I just made it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default is to insert all columns, so

```
INSERT INTO OrderMenu VALUES(1234, 111, 2);
```

is really:

```
INSERT INTO OrderMenu (orderid,pid,quantity,rowtotal)
  VALUES(1234, 111, 2);
ORA-00947: not enough values.
```

You have to use:

```
INSERT INTO OrderMenu (orderid,pid,quantity) VALUES(1234, 111, 2);
```

---

Your trigger has errors: `SET rowtotal = rowtotal+1;` <-- semicolon.

Using `AFTER` will give you this error:

```
ORA-04091: table <schema>.ORDERMENU is mutating
```

You seem to be trying to add 1 to the current value of rowtotal for any row. That value will be 0+1 every time you don't specify a rowtotal. However, it will never actually update your row (using `BEFORE`):

```
CREATE TRIGGER orderMenuTrig BEFORE INSERT ON OrderMenu
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE TrigOrderID NUMBER;
BEGIN
     TrigOrderID := :new.orderid;
     -- this SQL will always be empty (not update anything)
     -- since there are NO rows with the orderid to be inserted
     UPDATE OrderMenu 
        SET rowtotal = rowtotal+1
      WHERE trigorderid = OrderMenu.orderid;
END;
/
```

You can use this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER orderMenuTrig BEFORE INSERT ON OrderMenu
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
     :new.rowtotal := coalesce(:new.rowtotal,0) + 1;
END;
/
```

Comment: No need for a SELECT statement in the trigger, you can simply assign the new value: `:new.rowtotal := :new.rowtotal + 1;` or better `:new.rowtotal := coalesce(:new.rowtotal,0) + 1;`